# How to move text from inside the checkbox/label

Tags: html, css

**My problem is, they overlap each other**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltZ8w.png

**I need to do like this:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/roBun.png

What can I do? I just need to line text with my input checkbox, as I showed in my picture, any suggestions?

```css
.round {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.round label {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 28px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 28px;
}

.round label:after {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    content: "";
    height: 6px;
    left: 7px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 12px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    background-color: #66bb6a;
    border-color: #66bb6a;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #3CC070;
}

.tasks input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    border-color: #66bb6a;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #3CC070;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
                <div>
                    <div> <input type="checkbox" class="input" checked>
                        <label>Make some cash</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="round">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
                        <label for="checkbox" class="text"> Make</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Make the circle be show as a pseudo element rather than as a border to the actual element itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add pseudo `Before` for `label` and add text inside it.

*remove label content*  `<label for="checkbox" class="text"></label>`

`label.text:before {
    content: "click";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 37px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
}`

```css
.round {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.round label {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 28px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 28px;
}

label.text:before {
   content: "click";
   display: inline-block;
   left: 37px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 4px;
}
.round label:after {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    content: "";
    height: 6px;
    left: 7px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 12px;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    background-color: #66bb6a;
    border-color: #66bb6a;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #3CC070;
}

.tasks input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
    border-color: #66bb6a;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: #3CC070;
}

.round input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
                <div>
                    <div> <input type="checkbox" class="input" checked>
                        <label>Make some cash</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="round">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
                        <label for="checkbox" class="text"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks, man. But how can I use my  text-decoration: line-through; on content: ""?